# Connection fails when using putty + SOCKS firefox

Tags: networking, router, ssh, putty, dd-wrt

I originally posted this in the DD-WRT forums but no one is responding there so I'm posting it here, hopefully I could get a response.

Okay, so I'm trying to SSH remotely into my secondary home router which is running DD-WRT. I haven't tried this remotely, only locally.

I've set up DDNS (no-ip) on my primary router running stock firmware, I've tried setting it up on my DD-WRT router but it doesn't work because I disabled WAN.

- Primary router is at 192.168.1.1
- Secondary (DD-WRT) router is at 192.168.1.2

I also tried port forwarding the DDNS connection from my primary to secondary router because I think it would help somehow, I don't know about this.

**My port forwarding settings:**

[image]

**Here are my putty settings:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(used auto and dynamic)

**My DD-WRT router settings:**

[image]

[image]

**Firefox setting for SOCKS proxy:**

[image]

**The putty session works:**

[image]

I followed [this video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kECJVD08Fi0&list=LL3lTHGUILe6EwMhafLejGPw&index=5) to get my two routers set up if it helps to know.

I'm pretty sure I got everything right, but when I load any webpage I get two errors:

> 1. The connection was reset
> 2. Secure connection failed

And that's all the info I could possibly provide for troubleshooting, I've done my part on giving good useful info, so please help me out here.

EDIT: I also followed [this guide on setting up DD-WRT with SSH](https://advancedhomeserver.com/dd-wrt-ssh-secure-public-wifi/)

Comment: Here on Super User the problem is considered to be solved when one of the answers is accepted; you don't need to change the title to indicate this. If you have your own solution then please post it as an answer and then accept it (you may have to wait some time before accepting your own answer).

Answer (score 0):

i don't get what is the idea here ...

what you are setting up is called port forwarding or ssh tunnelling

you don't need to setup socks proxy for this. (in fact you don't have any socks proxy)

In putty : connection->ssh->tunnels  add port 443 and the destination then connect to it. then in firefox use "no proxy" and just browse to https://127.x.x.x

also in the remote router ssh== 22 not 443. if you change this you wont be able to ssh to the router.

also port forwarding in the router is only useful if used on connecting thru the wan interface towards a server in the lan.  ( router A behind router B (lan--wan ?)

Comment: I've got it working, the issue was with my ISP, I had to configure VLAN tagging to get it to work and it worked with my settings above unchanged, so the settings were not causing the problem.